# Add new elements in Combobox, Dropdown list not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am binding ComboBox based on the code-behind,below is my XAML and Code Behind:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxBindingDatabase.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,60,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" IsEditable="True"/>
    <TextBox Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="135,159,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" />
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="384,165,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
    <TextBox Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="368,0,0,172" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="115" />
</Grid>
```

And Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindComboBox(comboBox1);
    }

    ArrayList b = new ArrayList();

    public void BindComboBox(ComboBox comboBoxName)
    {

        b.Add("a");
        b.Add("b");
        b.Add("c");
        b.Add("d");
        comboBoxName.ItemsSource = b;  
        comboBoxName.DisplayMemberPath = Name;
        comboBoxName.SelectedValuePath = Name;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        b.Add(textBox2.Text);
        foreach (string s in b)
        {
            comboBox1.ItemsSource = b;
            comboBox1.DisplayMemberPath = Name;
            comboBox1.SelectedValuePath = Name;
        }

    }

}
```

So when I first run the project, the ComcoBox show a,b,c d as the dropdown list. But when I input some new letters in textbox and click the button, the ArrayList b do add new letters into list, and i am trying re-bind the combobox, but it doesn't work. It still show a,b,c,d thought the i saw ArrarList b do increment.

Why the ComboBox not re-binding? Is there anyway to dynamically add elements into ComboBox based on Code Behind rather just simply item.add method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there some crazy reason you are setting the `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath` to the `Name` of the `MainWindow`??

Answer (score 2):

You should use an ObservableCollection instead. and you don't have to bind again inside the button click even as the collection will trigger change notifications whenever a new item is added and the combobox will be updated.

```
  ObservableCollection<string> b= new ObservableCollection<string>();

  public void BindComboBox(ComboBox comboBoxName)
    {

        b.Add("a");
        b.Add("b");
        b.Add("c");
        b.Add("d");

        comboBoxName.ItemsSource = b;  


    }


 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        b.Add(textBox2.Text);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In WPF its bad practice to directly reference UIControls in the code behind.
Your controls should be bound to Data, and when you change the Data the UI should be updated.

Here is a small example of what you are tring to do with a lot less references to UIControls

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="233" Width="405" Name="UI">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
        <StackPanel>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" Name="comboBox1" IsEditable="True"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="textbox1" />
            <Button Content="Button" Tag="{Binding ElementName=textbox1, Path=Text}" Name="button1" Click="button1_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _myList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyList.Add("a");
            MyList.Add("b");
            MyList.Add("c");
            MyList.Add("d");
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> MyList
        {
            get { return _myList; }
            set { _myList = value; }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyList.Add((sender as Button).Tag.ToString());
        }
     }
```

Comment: Very Cool! Thanks for providing better programming technique